# CORS on CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm creating a JSON webservice in CakePHP 1.3.

I want to be able to send AJAX requests from a different server to this webservice.

I know this is a cinch in Cake 2+, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out for v1.3. [Based on what I have found in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Request-Handling.html), I have attempted the following in my controller:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

function beforeFilter() {
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    $this->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    $this->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
    $this->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With');
    $this->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, x-xsrf-token');
    $this->header('Access-Control-Max-Age','172800');
}
```

This unfortunately results in `500 ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`.

I have attempted to do `$this->response->header` instead of `$this->header`, and same problem. I've also attempted `header` instead of `$this->header`, and again I'm getting a server response of `500`. I have *also* attempted moving the `header` block into my action in the controller, into the top-level app_controller.php file, into the bootstrap.php file, and into the view file itself (with every variation of `header`, `$this->header`, and `$this->response->header` attempted). Removing `Configure::write('debug', 0);` does not solve the issue.

Heck, I even have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Although that doesn't seem to do anything. I have `mod_headers.load` in my mods-available folder in Apache as well.

Anyone know how to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in CakePHP 1.3?

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I know this is an old post but I jut want to answer this to help others.

Comment: Where do you add this line?

Comment: @BrendaOliviaMartis you can set it anywhere in your controllers I believe. I set mine in `AppController->beforeFilter`

Answer (score 0):

[@Restie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093978/327074) is correct but it's not clear why. In CakePHP 1.3, in the controller library, the header method is just a wrapper onto the PHP `header` function:

```
function header($status) {
    header($status);
}
```

So `$this->header` should work perfectly. The mistake is to copy the Java style for setting headers which takes two parameters:

> `$this->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');`

For [`header`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in PHP land you have to switch it to:

```
$this->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```